# Retrieve data from a List

Tags: java, android

Sorry if the heading is misleading, i couldn't quite put it in words.

[Rotten Tomatoes](http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json?apikey=9htuhtcb4ymusd73d4z6jxcj)

The list runs fine and looks fine for what i am doing. What i am planning on doing is have a details page now with the synopsis etc. I thought about passing the ID of the movie that is passed on.

If i click on a movie, how can i, in the next page set the image of that movie, the text etc. Basically get all the data i need from the selected movie?

The source code can be found here - [Github](https://github.com/stillie/ParsingWithGSON/tree/master)

Screenshot (Terrible looking but its just messing around):

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Pass it via intent.?

Comment: you can try this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm. and save the data after parsing into a map object with the ID as the key.

Comment: Parse the JSON and save it to hashmap. On click of any item retrieve that content using its instance using the unique id and pass it  via intent

Comment: @x10sion I am not sure if this is what you are looking for . I guess you have to parse all the data at a time and store it locally. While moving forward to next section , load the data at the +1 index. If not then dynamically read indexes every time user want to move to next movie. And passing data can be done by intent with Parcelable interface.

Comment: Please have a look at the source code in the edited question

The thing with passing the data via intent is that all the data i need is not available on the list, there is other data that i need like the actors etc

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problemm in my project but your seems similar so i will give you my solution in order to help.

In my case i was retrieving stocks from a database and each stock had extra 15 prices which i wanted to show everytime i tapped on a stock so check the below answer.

**Code:**

I created an OBject with `String[]` to help me retrieve all those 15 prices for each stock and then pass it through `Intent`.

```
public class StockList {

    private String stockCurrentName;
    private String stockCurrentPrice;
    private String stockImage;
    private String[] restPrices;

    public StockList(String stockCurrentName, String stockCurrentPrice, String stockImage, String[] restPrices) {
        this.stockCurrentName = stockCurrentName;
        this.stockCurrentPrice = stockCurrentPrice;
        this.stockImage = stockImage;
        this.restPrices = restPrices;
    }

    public String getStockCurrentName() {
        return stockCurrentName;
    }

    public void setStockCurrentName(String stockCurrentName) {
        this.stockCurrentName = stockCurrentName;
    }

    public String getStockCurrentPrice() {
        return stockCurrentPrice;
    }

    public void setStockCurrentPrice(String stockCurrentPrice) {
        this.stockCurrentPrice = stockCurrentPrice;
    }

    public String getStockImage() {
        return stockImage;
    }

    public void setStockImage(String stockImage) {
        this.stockImage = stockImage;
    }

    public String[] getRestPrices() {
        return restPrices;
    }

    public void setRestPrices(String[] restPrices) {
        this.restPrices = restPrices;
    }
}
```

Then is how i retrieved the data:

```
public class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public JsonReadTask() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListLoaderActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle(R.string.waiting);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.get_stocks));
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(ListLoaderActivity.this,
                        RefreshActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                ListLoaderActivity.this.finish();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(ListLoaderActivity.this,
                        RefreshActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                ListLoaderActivity.this.finish();
            }
            return answer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ListDrawer();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }// end async task

    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        task.execute(new String[]{url});
    }

    public void ListDrawer() {
        customList = new ArrayList<StockList>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("metoxes");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
//for each stock i get its prices. 
//In your List for each movie you can get its synopsis and anything else you need.
                name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                price = jsonChildNode.optString("price");
                price1 = jsonChildNode.optString("price1");
                price2 = jsonChildNode.optString("price2");
                price3 = jsonChildNode.optString("price3");
                price4 = jsonChildNode.optString("price4");
                price5 = jsonChildNode.optString("price5");
                price6 = jsonChildNode.optString("price6");
                price7 = jsonChildNode.optString("price7");
                price8 = jsonChildNode.optString("price8");
                price9 = jsonChildNode.optString("price9");
                price10 = jsonChildNode.optString("price10");
                price11 = jsonChildNode.optString("price11");
                price12 = jsonChildNode.optString("price12");
                price13 = jsonChildNode.optString("price13");
                price14 = jsonChildNode.optString("price14");
                price15 = jsonChildNode.optString("price15");

                image = jsonChildNode.optString("image");

                justPrices = new String[]{price1, price2,
                        price3, price4, price5, price6, price7, price8, price9,
                        price10, price11, price12, price13, price14, price15};
                loipesTimes = new String[]{"1st Day Value " + price1, "2nd Day Value " + price2, "3rd Day Value " + price3, "4th Day Value " + price4, "5th Day Value " + price5,
                        "6th Day Value " + price6, "7th Day Value " + price7, "8th Day Value " + price8, "9th Day Value " + price9,
                        "10th Day Value " + price10, "11th Day Value " + price11, "12th Day Value " + price12, "13th Day Value " + price13, "14th Day Value " + price14, "15th Day Value " + price15};
                customList.add(new StockList(name, price, image, justPrices));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(ListLoaderActivity.this,
                    RefreshActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            ListLoaderActivity.this.finish();
        }

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new MyStocksAdapter(ListLoaderActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, customList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        startList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

And then pass the through `Intent`

```
private void registerCallClickBack() {
        startList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
                tv1 = (TextView) viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.stock_name);
                tv2 = (TextView) viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.stock_price);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListLoaderActivity.this, StockItem.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", tv1.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("price", tv2.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("stockInfo", customList.get(position).getRestPrices());
                intent.putExtra("stockImage", customList.get(position).getStockImage());
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
            }
        }
    }
```

I guess you can use it like this and this will help you get it done!!!
Hope i helped you!!!

Comment: It is better to use Parcelable. This makes our coding simpler. Pls check my answer

Answer (score 1):

if you show us what are you doing in your code we could help you more but to pass data from one activity to another you can use `intent` example :

```
String value= getIntent().getStringExtra("keyName");

Intent intent = new Intent(this, RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("keyName", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                YourObject item = arraylist.get(arg2);
                TextView textView = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView);


                Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);        
                intent.putExtra("textview_value", textView.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use intent for pass data from one activity to another exactly how Moudiz say and then retrieve received data like this

```
String value;

Intent intent = getIntent();
    value = intent.getStringExtra("keyName");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would have pasted your code then it would be easier to understand your actual problem . But with the data and json given :
1.if you having problem in retrieving data from Json then please follow below link :
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial

2. If passing to next Activity then it would be done using Intent:

> ```
> String value= getIntent().getStringExtra("Key");
>      Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataClassNameHere.class);
>     intent.putExtra("key", value);
>     startActivity(intent);
> ```